# Emulator won't run

Tags: android, xml

I create a New Application Project, and choose Android 2.2 for Minimum Required SDK and Target SDK, for Compile With; API8, it tells me I can't Create Activity, so I accept. I create package and a class named MainActivity.java in src and activity_main.xml in layout, before all that, I create

[image: Screenshot of selection]

When I write everything correctly (I think) and Run as > Android Application it stops and I get this message in the console:

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Could you please attach your manifest.xml file?
Perhaps you declared inside of it the minimum SDK to be = 10.
Your AVD runs API level :8.

Comment: Sorry, the android:minSdkVersion was 10 in my post, now its 8 http://oi62.tinypic.com/esp1rs.jpg and when its Run, it stopped again and here is the msgs in the console http://oi59.tinypic.com/i53jo2.jpg

Comment: Could you post your java and Xml code please?

Comment: Sure .. http://oi60.tinypic.com/2zteqa8.jpg

Comment: @weinek: Why are you posting your codes and config files outside of SO? You can post it here so the info remained with your post since there's no guarantee that tinypic.com will always be available. Note: You can use the functions in SO editor to include codes or images in your post.

Comment: Umm! What is SO editor?

Comment: The same editor you use when you post or edit a question.